# how to remove "&#160;" string from html using java?

Tags: java, regex

I wanted to remove `"&#160;"`string from a string which is in a html tag .I am using something like

```
nonhtml = nonhtml.replaceAll("&#160;", "");
```

But in this approach I have to specifically remove others also like `&nbsp` .I donot want to use jsoup here as i know what and all html tag I am dealing with .Any clue on this would be helpful .

Answer (score 0):

The following code is pretty simple Java, and it looks like (to me) that the solution you have provided works just fine on my end.

Perhaps remember:

- `String.replace(String text, String replaceText)`
- `String.replaceAll(String regularExpression, String replaceText)`

***... are slightly different.***  The latter (the one cited in the question), accepts a "Regular-Expression" - which is compiled by the class `java.lang.String`  Look closely at the java documentation pages for `class String` to see where a Regular-Expression, not a simple String is used as a parameter in "Replace-String" methods...  (Google JDK Java-Docs for java.lang.String)

This code, for me, works just fine!  However, if the first parameter to the `replaceAll` method were changed, and the chabge included any characters that require escaping courtesy of Reg-Ex, then the method would fail.  For this simple case, it was fine.  See: [replaceAll(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and [replace(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-)

```
String nonhtml = "<HTML>\n<BODY>\n<H1>Simple Test</H1>\n&nbsp;&nbsp;Hello,<BR />\n<PRE> how are you? </PRE>\n&#160;&#160;</BODY></HTML>\n";
System.out.println(nonhtml);
System.out.println(nonhtml.replaceAll("&nbsp;", "").replaceAll("&#160;", ""));
```

Produced this output:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<H1>Simple Test</H1>
&nbsp;&nbsp;Hello,<BR />
<PRE> how are you? </PRE>
&#160;&#160;</BODY></HTML>

<HTML>
<BODY>
<H1>Simple Test</H1>
Hello,<BR />
<PRE> how are you? </PRE>
</BODY></HTML>
```